# How can I tell an if statement to skip a file but continue onto the next file if a certain condition is met?

Tags: bash

```
for f in ~/Desktop/Uploads/*.flv; do
if /usr/local/bin/ffprobe ${f} 2>&1 | egrep 'Stream #0:0.+flv1'; then
<what do I put here for the batch file to skip the file and continue?>
else
if /usr/local/bin/ffprobe ${f} 2>&1 | egrep 'Stream #0:1.+speex'; then
    /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ${f} -vn -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ar 48000 -async 1 ${f/%.flv/.m4a}
    SPEEX_ADD="-i ${f/%.flv/.m4a}"
    SPEEX_MAP="-map 1:0"
    SPEEX_TRASH="rmtrash ${f/%.flv/.m4a}"
    ~/Desktop/Uploads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i ${f} ${SPEEX_ADD} -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0:0 ${SPEEX_MAP} ${f/%.flv/.mp4} && rmtrash ${f} && ${SPEEX_TRASH}
else
~/Desktop/Uploads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i ${f} -vcodec copy -an ${f/%.flv/.mp4} && rmtrash ${f}
fi
done
```

I'm using a batch file to convert video files but I need help. What can I put in that third line that will make the batch file skip over files with flv1 video but continue onto the next file? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue`.  Check the `bash` man page for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `continue` keyword.  Have a look at the Loop Control page in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loopcontrol.html)